# What is the actual pricing for AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

AWS EC2 Container Service official webpage says:

> There is no additional charge for Amazon EC2 Container Service. You pay for AWS resources (e.g. EC2 instances or EBS volumes) you create to store and run your application.

What does that mean if I host my application that would run on the micro EC2 instance and it would have been scheduled to run only once a day. The execution would take 1 hour.

Does it mean I pay for 1 hour or do I also pay for the EC2 instance while it's idle? Is in this case AWS Beanstalk better?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about managing a business relationship, communicating between the question OP and a third party, and/or dealing with a legal issue. In other words, it's not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic]. You might be able to get help from the Customer Service for the company you are interfacing with. If you want an interpretation of legal requirements, it might be appropriate to ask on [law.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what do you mean *idle* ?

In AWS EC2 from pricing point of view an instance is running or stopped - if your instance is terminated, there's no instance so you don't pay.

If your instance is running you pay for it, wether you have some execution code or not.

If your instance is stopped, you don't pay for EC2 usage but you will still pay for other charges : if you have an elastic IP address you will pay for it, if you have EBS storage you will pay for it.

Note: remember that cloud is about maximizing the resources you use. if you dont use the resources, stop them so you don't get charge.

You can read about the [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloud-container-management/)

> **Resource Efficiency** – A containerized application can make very
>   efficient use of resources. You can choose to run multiple, unrelated
>   containers on the same EC2 instance in order to make good use of all
>   available resources. You could, for example, decide to run a mix of
>   short-term image processing jobs and long-running web services on the
>   same instance.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I was hoping that EC2 instances running under ECS would be somehow dynamically handled so that I would pay only for what I use, not the whole instance that I don't need any other time, except when the app is executing. Then for every other little app I have to host, there needs to be different EC2 instance running under the ECS?

Comment: so when you schedule your app to run - make sure you stop the underlying EC2 instance not to occur the fees from the server running it

Comment: I was hoping for something like this: There could be multiple apps running on the same EC2 instance handled by ECS. So the actual EC2 instance would be fully used.

Comment: that you can do : [blog resource](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cloud-container-management/) You can choose to run multiple, unrelated containers on the same EC2 instance in order to make good use of all available resources. You could, for example, decide to run a mix of short-term image processing jobs and long-running web services on the same instance

Comment: thats what cloud is about : try to maximize the resources you use. if you dont use the resources, stop them so you don't get charge